# Why was my post about improvising filter grilles closed as needing details/clarity?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Home Improvement Stack Exchange post: [How can I improvise Filter Grilles, rather than buy the manufacturer's Coarse Dust Pre-Filtration Kit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/272727/how-can-i-improvise-filter-grilles-rather-than-buy-the-manufacturers-coarse-du)

Apologia, English ISN'T my first language. But why "This question needs details or clarity"? Doubtless, my question was clear enough to the 2 commenters who responded fittingly. Don't hesitate to edit my question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was voted on by the community to close with the reason "needs details or clarity" and "opinion based". After the question was closed, reviewers looked at the edits and the request to reopen and declined to reopen with the reason "original close reason(s) were not resolved". Looking at the edits, they appear to be superficial, and not providing more details that the community may be looking for.

Reviewing the question myself, a few things stand out:

- Asking how to build your own product to replace the vendor supplied one could be seen as bordering on a hobby project rather than a home improvement question.
- The number of links to vendor websites could be interpreted as spam. We get a lot of content that pretends to be legitimate questions and answers but use that to push links to products they are selling.
- The phrase "Disregard — and I need no assistance with..." may be quickly viewed by a reviewer as you indicating you no longer have the problem if they did not read it in detail.

We do recommend that users voting to close a question provide details on how the question can be improved. And before the question was deleted, asking for that guidance in the comments would have been a good next step. Unfortunately, it's past the 10 day grace period and the community bot has marked the question for deletion.

Please have a look at the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour). If you can ask the question with more details, such as an analysis of the construction of the current filter, it may be appropriate to post a new question.

Comment: I just tried to look at the question, and it now goes to a 404 page.  Given that this is DIY SE, the 404 page features duct tape.  A smile ensued. :)

Comment: Just for posterity purposes, without seeing the question, I think your 2nd bullet-point may have been the biggest issue.  The 3rd bullet-point would be a reviewer's error, and would necessitate reversal.  The 1st bullet-point could be discussed, but IMO, sounds on-topic given the context.